# How to create more System Administrators?

Tags: profile

[image]How to create more system administrators?

I already have 2 System administrator (profile) created.

When I was trying to create a new System administrator, I am not getting the option from Profile drop down as System administrator.
It seems like there is no remaining license. Can i increase the license number?If can, how to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to create a User with Sys Admin Profile OR Are you trying to create a Profile. If you try to create a Profile you will not get a dropdown as Profile rather you would get as Existing Profile Dropdown to select any Profile from which you can create another custom profile, Only If you try to create a User you will get an Option Dropdown as Profile.

If you are trying to create a User and not getting the System Administrator option for that user might indicate that you are out of Salesforce Licenses.

Comment: You are running out of Salesforce licenses

Comment: You **HAVE** run out of licenses @Ashwani corrected it for ya :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only 2 Salesforce licenses, which means you can only create 2 System Administrators.
If you have your own developer org, you can't have more than 2 Salesforce licenses.
If you are a Salesforce Partner, you can request Partner Developer Edition.
If you have any other edition, you can purchase additional licenses from Salesforce.